# Deserialize nested JSON structures to Django model objects

Tags: python, json, django, deserialization, json-deserialization

I need to consume a service that sends JSON responses containing JSON-serialized nested structures, which I would like to deserialize and store in my database - my application uses Django.

Business rules are the following:

1. The query returns objects which always have an `id` property which is a unique integer, often a `createdAt` property and an `updatedAt` property, both with datetime data, and then several other properties which are primitive types (int, float, str, datetime, etc.), and several properties that can be another object or an array of objects.
2. In case the property value is an object, then the parent relates to it through a 'foreign key'. In case it's an array of objects, then we have two scenarios: either the objects of the array relate to the parent through a 'foreign key', or the parent and each member of the array are related through a 'many-to-many' relation.
3. I need to mirror each of those objects in my database, so each model has an `id` field which is the primary key, but it's not autogenerated, because the real ids will be provided with the imported data.
4. The relations between all those entities are already mirrored in my model schema. *I adopted this approach (mirroring data structure) because if I flatten the received data to save it all into a single table, there will be horrendous replication, defying all data normalization rules.*
5. For every root object, I need to do this:

   - check whether there is already a record in database for that `id`
   - create a new record in case there isn't
   - update the existing record in case there is already one (update might be skipped if `updatedAt` values are the same for both the record and the incoming data
   - recursively repeat these same steps for each nested object that is the provided value for one of its parent's properties.

Below I'm reproducing a very simplified sample of the data I receive from the service and the models I in which I want to store it. The real thing is *much, much more* bulky and complex than that, and that's why I'm so wanting to learn a way of letting the ORM take care of the problem, should it be able to. Hard-coding the whole thing is taking forever, aside of being pretty error-prone and creating a maintenance hell should the data schema change in the future.

**EDIT**: A link to a [previous simplified version of the following **JSON** and **Models**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59428440/3)*

#### JSON sample:

```
{
  "id": 37125965,
  "number": "029073432019403",
  "idCommunication": "1843768",
  "docReceivedAt": {
    "date": "2019-12-20 08:46:42"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:14"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:32"
  },
  "branch": {
    "id": 20,
    "name": "REGIONAL OFFICE #3",
    "address": "457 Beau St., S\u00e3o Paulo, SP, 08547-003",
    "active": true,
    "createdAt": {
      "date": "2013-02-14 23:12:30"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "date": "2019-05-09 13:40:47"
    }
  },
  "modality": {
    "id": 1,
    "valor": "CITA\u00c7\u00c3O",
    "descricao": "CITA\u00c7\u00c3O",
    "active": true,
    "createdAt": {
      "date": "2014-08-29 20:47:56"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "date": "2014-08-29 20:47:56"
    }
  },
  "operation": {
    "id": 12397740,
    "number": "029073432019403",
    "startedAt": {
      "date": "2019-11-07 22:28:25"
    },
    "managementType": 27,
    "assessmentValue": 5000000,
    "createdAt": {
      "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:30"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:30"
    },
    "operationClass": {
      "id": 22,
      "name": "A\u00c7\u00c3O RESCIS\u00d3RIA",
      "createdAt": {
        "date": "2014-02-28 20:24:55"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "date": "2014-02-28 20:24:55"
      }
    },
    "evaluator": {
      "id": 26798,
      "name": "JANE DOE",
      "level": 1,
      "active": true,
      "createdAt": {
        "date": "2017-02-22 22:54:04"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "date": "2017-03-15 18:03:20"
      },
      "evaluatorsOffice": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "ACME",
        "area": 4,
        "active": true,
        "createdAt": {
          "date": "2014-02-28 20:25:16"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
          "date": "2014-02-28 20:25:16"
        }
      },
      "evaluatorsOffice_id": 7
    },
    "operationClass_id": 22,
    "evaluator_id": 26798
  },
  "folder": {
    "id": 16901241,
    "singleDocument": false,
    "state": 0,
    "IFN": "00409504174201972",
    "closed": false,
    "dataHoraAbertura": {
      "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:31"
    },
    "dataHoraTransicao": {
      "date": "2024-12-20 09:01:31"
    },
    "titulo": "CONTROL FOLDER REF. OP. N. 029073432019403",
    "createdAt": {
      "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:32"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:32"
    },
    "subjects": [
      {
        "id": 22255645,
        "main": true,
        "createdAt": {
          "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:32"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
          "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:32"
        },
        "subjectClass": {
          "id": 20872,
          "name": "SPECIAL RETIREMENT PROCESS",
          "active": true,
          "regulation": "8.213/91, 53.831/64, 83.080/79, 2.172/97, 1.663/98, 9.711/98, 9.528/97 AND 9.032/95",
          "glossary": "SPECIAL RETIREMENT APPLICATION DUE TO HAZARDOUS LABOR CONDITION FOR 15+/20+/25+ YEARS",
          "createdAt": {
            "date": "2013-10-18 16:22:44"
          },
          "updatedAt": {
            "date": "2013-10-18 16:22:44"
          },
          "parent": {
            "id": 20866,
            "name": "RETIREMENT BENEFITS",
            "active": true,
            "createdAt": {
              "date": "2013-10-18 16:22:44"
            },
            "updatedAt": {
              "date": "2013-10-18 16:22:44"
            },
            "parent": {
              "id": 20126,
              "name": "SOCIAL SECURITY",
              "active": true,
              "createdAt": {
                "date": "2013-10-18 16:22:42"
              },
              "updatedAt": {
                "date": "2013-10-18 16:22:42"
              }
            },
            "parent_id": 20126
          },
          "parent_id": 20866
        },
        "subjectClass_id": 20872
      }
    ],
    "person": {
      "id": 7318,
      "isClient": true,
      "isRelated": false,
      "name": "SOCSEC CO.",
      "createdAt": {
        "date": "2013-02-14 23:11:43"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "date": "2019-11-18 16:05:07"
      }
    },
    "operation": {
      "id": 12397740,
      "number": "029073432019403",
      "startedAt": {
        "date": "2019-11-07 22:28:25"
      },
      "managementType": 27,
      "assessmentValue": 5000000,
      "createdAt": {
        "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:30"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "date": "2019-12-20 09:01:30"
      }
    },
    "section": {
      "id": 311,
      "name": "PROTOCOL",
      "address": "457 Beau St., ground floor, S\u00e3o Paulo, SP, 08547-003",
      "active": true,
      "management": false,
      "onlyDistribution": true,
      "createdAt": {
        "date": "2013-02-14 23:12:31"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "date": "2019-07-05 16:40:34"
      },
      "branch": {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "REGIONAL OFFICE #3",
        "address": "457 Beau St., S\u00e3o Paulo, SP, 08547-003",
        "active": true,
        "createdAt": {
          "date": "2013-02-14 23:12:30"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
          "date": "2019-05-09 13:40:47"
        }
      },
      "branch_id": 20
    },
    "person_id": 7318,
    "operation_id": 12397740,
    "section_id": 311
  },
  "branch_id": 20,
  "modality_id": 1,
  "operation_id": 12397740,
  "folder_id": 16901241
}
```

### Models.py sample:

```
from django.db import models


class Section(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    management = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    onlyDistribution = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()
    branch = models.ForeignKey('Branch', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    isClient = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    isRelated = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()


class SubjectClass(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    regulation = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    glossary = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('SubjectClass', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Subject(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()
    folder = models.ForeignKey('Folder', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    subjectClass = models.ForeignKey(SubjectClass, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Folder(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    singleDocument = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    IFN = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=True)
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(SubjectClass, through=Subject, through_fields=('folder', 'subjectClass'))
    interestedEntity = models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class EvaluatorsOffice(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    area = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()


class Evaluator(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()
    evaluatorsOffice = models.ForeignKey(EvaluatorsOffice, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class OperationClass(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()


class Operation(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=True)
    startedAt = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    managementType = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    assessmentValue = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()
    operationClass = models.ForeignKey(OperationClass, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    evaluator = models.ForeignKey(Evaluator, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Branch(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()


class Modality(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()


class CommunicationRecord(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=True)
    idCommunication = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=True)
    docReceivedAt = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField()
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField()
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    modality = models.ForeignKey(Modality, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    operation = models.ForeignKey(Operation, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

## EDIT (ref. [DRF Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)):

I'm trying to follow [Max Malysh I Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977620/max-malysh-i-reinstate-monica)'s suggestion, and I started to work on a recursive serializer:

```
from django.db.models import Manager, Model, Field, DateTimeField, ForeignKey
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer


class RecursiveSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    manager: Manager
    field_dict: dict

    def __init__(self, target_manager: Manager, data: dict, **kwargs):
        self.manager = target_manager
        self.Meta.model = self.manager.model
        self.field_dict = {f.name: f for f in self.manager.model._meta.fields}
        instance = None
        data = self.process_data(data)
        pk_name = self.manager.model._meta.pk.name
        if pk_name in data:
            try:
                instance = target_manager.get(pk=data[pk_name])
            except target_manager.model.DoesNotExist:
                pass
        super().__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)

    def process_data(self, data: dict):
        processed_data = {}
        for name, value in data.items():
            field: Field = self.field_dict.get(name)
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                if isinstance(field, ForeignKey):
                    processed_data[name] = self.__class__(field.related_model.objects, data=value)
                    continue
                elif len(value) == 1 and 'date' in value and isinstance(field, DateTimeField):
                    processed_data[name] = value['date']
                    continue
            processed_data[name] = value
        return processed_data

    class Meta:
        model: Model = None
        fields = '__all__'
```

However, it does a weird thing: when first run, against an empty database, it only creates the last and most deeply nested object. In the second run, it does nothing and returns a `code='unique'` validation error saying that such object already exists.

Now I must say I'm quite new to Python and Django (I come from .NET development) and the difficulties I'm facing about this task begin to look very awkward for me. I've been reading docs about Django and DRF, which helped me less than I expected. Yet I refuse to believe aforementioned language and framework lack resources for performing such a trivial operation. So, If I'm missing something very obvious, as it seems, for lack of knowledge of mine, I'll be grateful if someone teaches me what I seem not to know here.

Comment: Check out serializers in django rest framework.

Comment: @MaxMalyshIReinstateMonica, thanks, I'm trying hard to use those. I needed to install [drf-writable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) as well, and thus I could insert new records, but not to update existing ones: I get `rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError` all around, saying that `id` field should be unique, a problem that I honestly have no idea of how to overcome. In my case, a deserialized JSON object should *always* replace the previous record in db, should the `id` be the same.

Comment: The name `entityFvinculations` (in JSON) doesn't exist in models.

Comment: @hynekcer, my bad! I updated my samples to a more realistic version of what I really have to deal with. It's still very abridged tho, except I kept the relations of a real sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally why I agree that *DRF is not useful for this case*: DRF defines an API and is similar to a view than to a model in many aspects: It defines which part of data should be exported. It is able to support all CRUD operations over the same data structure. There could be more APIs over the same data. Therefore it normal that serializers are separated from models. It is also frequently necessary to not change anything in models if a third party package should be a part of the new API. You need only Create and Update (no Read or Delete). You confirmed that you don't need any complicated security restrictions.

**EDIT** Main features of my code for your updated JSON and Models would be much more similar to yours. That doesn't make sense. I will write more comments and less change the code because it could lead to endless growing of the model and JSON to explain why you e.g. ignore some errors.

The important information to your assignment is that: 1. The data of "through" entity in all many to many relations are present in JSON (while never previously)  2. The `changedAt` timestamp of root entity is updated with every change of a nested entity in JSON, including all intermediate entities and even including the "through" entity.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class UpdateableModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def creupdate(cls, data: dict, save_main_instance: bool = True, no_optimization=False):
        primary_key_name = cls._meta.pk.name
        if primary_key_name not in data:
            raise ValueError(f'parameter \'data\' must contain \'{primary_key_name}\' key (model\'s primary key).')
        try:
            instance = cls.objects.get(pk=data[primary_key_name])
            at_instance = getattr(instance, 'atualizadoEm', None)
            at_data = data.get('atualizadoEm', None)
            operation = 'unchanged' if at_instance and at_data and at_instance >= at_data else 'updated'
            if operation == 'unchanged' and not no_optimizations:
                print(f'{operation} instance {primary_key_name} {instance.pk} from {instance._meta.model}')
                return instance
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            instance = cls()
            operation = 'created'
        many_to_many_instances = []
        for name, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                if len(value) == 1 and 'date' in value:
                    date_value = datetime.strptime(value['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    if timezone.is_naive(date_value):
                        date_value = timezone.make_aware(date_value)
                    new_value = date_value
                else:
                    foreign_key = cls._meta.get_field(name)
                    foreign_model = foreign_key.related_model
                    foreign_data: dict = value
                    foreign_instance = foreign_model.creupdate(foreign_data)
                    new_value = foreign_instance
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                remote_field = getattr(instance, name)
                obj_ids = []
                for remote_data in value:
                    assert isinstance(remote_data, dict) and remote_field.model._meta.pk.name in remote_data
                    obj_ids.append(remote_field.model.creupdate(remote_data, False).pk)
                many_to_many_instances.append((remote_field, obj_ids))
            else:
                new_value = value
            if operation != 'unchanged':
                setattr(instance, name, new_value)
        if save_main_instance and operation != 'unchanged':
            instance.save()
        print(f'{operation} instance {primary_key_name} {instance.pk} from {instance._meta.model}')
        for remote_field, obj_ids in many_to_many_instances:
            remote_field.add(*obj_ids)
        return instance
```

Notes:

- The many to many relationship is optimized to add all objects by one request to minimize save count if nothing is is changed. (It was written for the previous JSON structure without any explicit "through" data)
- Added assert instead of try ... except ValueError: pass (or FieldDoesNotExist).
  "Errors should never pass silently." [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - Especially in development. (An unknown `through` name is a similar error to an unknown normal attribute.)
- Added a parameter "no_optimization" and leave my logic to use "modifiedAt" only for the same entity, not to skip a check on the related entities. If an error occurs or if an update is ignored incorrectly by FieldDoesNotExist than the  state of the database can be updated later by replaying the data with no_optimization=True. If all entities use a timestamp then it is even *idempotent* and the data can be processed in any random order e.g. by repeating data from a period of time with some bugs. It is also useful for a check of your optimizations that you get the same state of the database by processing with and without optimizations - e.g. by comparing the exported sql dump. My experience is that an optimization depending on timestamp too much is a problem much later if no alternative way is prepared.

Comment: thank you! As I pointed out, I edit my post to updated my samples to a more realistic version of what I really have to deal with. It's still very abridged tho, except I kept the relations of a real sample.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I gave up using DRF and just created an extended abstract model for my other models to inherit from, and gave it the feature I needed, implemented as shown below.

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import FieldDoesNotExist
from django.utils import timezone


class UpdateableModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def creupdate(cls, data: dict, save_main_instance: bool = True):
        primary_key_name = cls._meta.pk.name
        if primary_key_name not in data:
            raise ValueError(f'parameter \'data\' must contain \'{primary_key_name}\' key (model\'s primary key).')
        try:
            instance = cls.objects.get(pk=data[primary_key_name])
            at_instance = getattr(instance, 'atualizadoEm', None)
            at_data = data.get('atualizadoEm', None)
            if at_instance and at_data and at_instance >= at_data:
                print(f'unchanged instance {primary_key_name} {instance.pk} from {instance._meta.model}')
                return instance
            operation = 'updated'
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            instance = cls()
            operation = 'created'
        many_to_many_instances = []
        for name, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                if len(value) == 1 and 'date' in value:
                    date_value = datetime.strptime(value['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    if timezone.is_naive(date_value):
                        date_value = timezone.make_aware(date_value)
                    setattr(instance, name, date_value)
                else:
                    foreign_key = cls._meta.get_field(name)
                    foreign_model = foreign_key.related_model
                    foreign_data: dict = value
                    foreign_instance = foreign_model.creupdate(foreign_data)
                    setattr(instance, name, foreign_instance)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                try:
                    relation_field = cls._meta.get_field(name)
                except FieldDoesNotExist:
                    relation_field = None
                if relation_field:
                    for through_data in value:
                        try:
                            through_model = getattr(instance, name).through
                            if isinstance(through_data,dict) and through_model._meta.pk.name in through_data:
                                many_to_many_instances.append(through_model.creupdate(through_data, False))
                        except ValueError:
                            pass
            else:
                setattr(instance, name, value)
        if save_main_instance:
            instance.save()
        print(f'{operation} instance {primary_key_name} {instance.pk} from {instance._meta.model}')
        for many_to_many_instance in many_to_many_instances:
            many_to_many_instance.save()
        return instance
```

Now, although it worked (I have just imported a ton of data using it), I won't mark this as an answer right now, for two reasons:

1. I'm willing to hear criticism to my implementation, that will point out flaws and ways to make it more robust and optimized.
2. I'm still hoping there are better solutions than mine. Only in case months go by and nothing shows up, then I'll assume there is none and will accept my own answer.

Comment: Your solution seems appropriate to your requirements and data.  (e.g. the field `entityA_id` is redundand for drf-writable-nested, but useful for your algorithm. Your code is perfectly DRY: uses only models and doesn't need any serializers definition, but it could lead to security problems. Imagine that someone adds a field "created_by" with a ForeignKey to auth.User and don't expect that it should be updated by JSON. That model should be never UpdateableModel, otherwise it opens a backdoor that even a new rogue site administrator user could be created by some unexpected JSON data.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your insights! I didn't think about the security problem. In my scenario, there's no risk, because sensible models don't inherit this class, besides I control the input, which is safe. Nonetheless,  this is important should anyone else use this code.

Comment: Even a reverse ManyToMany relation from EntityF to EntityRoot can be used to create or update extraneous root object that could easily permission data validation in such JSON. Yes the consumer side must absolutely rely on the permission validation on the data producer side with this nice general serializer.

Comment: Well, that abstract model is used in a specific set of models and those - even the root one - have no relationship with any user, group or permission data. And the "creupdate()" method is only called by a script that only runs in server. The only operation that will be exposed in a view is the command to start the script, no parameter will be passed by users. Is that enough to be in the safe side, I guess?... By the way, happy new year.

Comment: @hynekcer, if there seem to be something I'm not seeing here, please feel free to point out. I'd like to make this as safe as possible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, this is the way.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

[From Django Rest Framework: nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects)