# Is there an elegant way to flatten nested JSON with a django serializer?

Tags: python, json, django, nested, deserialization

I receive nested JSON from an API (I can't influence the structure). I want to flatten the nested fields while deserializing an object, ***using a django rest framework serializer***. How do I do this elegantly?

Here is my current approach, which works by using nested serializers and doing the flattening in the `.create()`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

from rest_framework import serializers

input_data = {
    "objectName": "Johnny",
    "geoInfo": {
        "latitude": 1.2,
        "longitude": 3.4,
    },
}

flattened_output = {
    "name": "Johnny",
    "lat": 1.2,
    "lon": 3.4,
}


@dataclass
class Thing:
    name: str
    lat: float
    lon: float


class TheFlattener(serializers.Serializer):
    class GeoInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        latitude = serializers.FloatField()
        longitude = serializers.FloatField()

    objectName = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, source="name")
    geoInfo = GeoInfoSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        geo_info = validated_data.pop("geoInfo")
        validated_data["lat"] = geo_info["latitude"]
        validated_data["lon"] = geo_info["longitude"]
        return Thing(**validated_data)


serializer = TheFlattener(data=input_data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
assert serializer.save() == Thing(**flattened_output)
```

I know that when serializing objects to JSON, you can reference nested/related objects in the `source` parameter e.g.

```
first_name = CharField(source="user.first_name")
```

which is really nice, but I haven't been able to find something similar for deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324341/django-rest-framework-serialize-data-from-nested-json-fields-to-plain-object) for providing the answer: `source="*"` flattens nested fields into the `validated_data`.

In this case, the solution looks like this:

```
class TheFlattener(serializers.Serializer):
    class GeoInfoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        latitude = serializers.FloatField(source="lat")  # rename here
        longitude = serializers.FloatField(source="lon")

    objectName = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, source="name")
    geoInfo = GeoInfoSerializer(source="*")  # unpack nested fields here

    def create(self, validated_data):  
        return Thing(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using recursing, something like that:

```py
def make_it_flat(inp):
    out = dict()
    
    def flatten(piece, name=''):
        if isinstance(piece, dict):
            for k,v in piece.items():
                flatten(v, f'{name}{k}_')
        elif isinstance(piece, list):
            for i, a in enumerate(piece):
                flatten(a, f'{name}{i}_')
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = piece
    flatten(inp)
    return out
```

Example:

```
>>> make_it_flat({22222: 'y', 1: {2: {3: ['a','b','c']}}})
{'22222': 'y', '1_2_3_0': 'a', '1_2_3_1': 'b', '1_2_3_2': 'c'}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it needs to be done using a DRF serializer. I've updated my post to emphasize this.

Answer (score 0):

for your situation I think your solution is as elegant as it gets, since you want to change the name of fields, not only flatten it.

However for larger nested Json you could define a flattening function (recursively/iteratively), or use some useful tool from pandas library such as:

**pandas.json_normalize** & pandas.DataFrame.**to_dict/to_json**

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Option1

```
from pandas import json_normalize

input_data = {
    "objectName": "Johnny",
    "geoInfo": {
        "latitude": 1.2,
        "longitude": 3.4,
    },
}

d = json_normalize(input_data).to_dict(into=OrderedDict)
print(type(d))
print(d)
```

Output 1:

```
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
OrderedDict([('objectName', OrderedDict([(0, 'Johnny')])), ('geoInfo.latitude', OrderedDict([(0, 1.2)])), ('geoInfo.longitude', OrderedDict([(0, 3.4)]))])
```

Option 2

```
d = json_normalize(input_data).to_dict(into=OrderedDict, 'list')
```

Output 2

```
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
OrderedDict([('objectName', ['Johnny']), ('geoInfo.latitude', [1.2]), ('geoInfo.longitude', [3.4])])
```

**Option 3**

```
d = json_normalize(input_data).to_dict(into=OrderedDict, orient='records')
```

**Output 3**

```
<class 'list'>
[OrderedDict([('objectName', 'Johnny'), ('geoInfo.latitude', 1.2), ('geoInfo.longitude', 3.4)])]
```

Option 4

```
d = json_normalize(input_data).to_dict('index', into=OrderedDict)
```

Output 4

```
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
OrderedDict([(0, {'objectName': 'Johnny', 'geoInfo.latitude': 1.2, 'geoInfo.longitude': 3.4})])
```

For this case **option 3** would be the best. But since it returns a list of length 1, **add [0]**.

Solution:

```
d = json_normalize(input_data).to_dict(orient='records')[0]
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>
{'objectName': 'Johnny', 'geoInfo.latitude': 1.2, 'geoInfo.longitude': 3.4}
```

For renaming fields a little more extra steps are required.

```
from pandas import json_normalize
from collections import OrderedDict

input_data = {
    "objectName": "Johnny",
    "geoInfo": {
        "latitude": 1.2,
        "longitude": 3.4,
    },
}

d = json_normalize(input_data).to_dict(orient='records', into=OrderedDict)[0]
N = len(d)
key_map = {"objectName": "name", "geoInfo.latitude": "lat", "geoInfo.longitude":"lon"}
# or use list ["name", "lat", "lon"] and access by index.
# I used dict key_map for cases when normal dict is used, instead of ordereddict
# (when into=OrderedDict argument is not given to pandas to_dict function)
for _ in range(N):
    k, v = d.popitem(last=False)
d[key_map[k]] = v

print(d)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Johnny'), ('lat', 1.2), ('lon', 3.4)])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it needs to be done using a DRF serializer. I've updated my post to emphasize this.

Comment: @binnev Please check if these posts can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428440/deserialize-nested-json-structures-to-django-model-objects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324341/django-rest-framework-serialize-data-from-nested-json-fields-to-plain-object